confidence interval and rejection
Assume I have a data sample $X_{1}, \dots X_{n}$ from a normal distribution. Then, we consider the following hypothesis
$$
H_0: \quad \mu = \mu_{0}
$$
and alternative
$$
H_1: \quad \mu \neq \mu_{0}
$$
Assume, based on data and using $t$-test we reject the null. Then, we can obviously, report a p-value. The question, does it make any sense to provide the the confidence interval, given that we rejected the null based on that confidence interval?

YES
I would consider this a best-practice.
While you are correct to recognize the relationship between hypothesis testing and confidence intervals, the confidence interval gives a range of "plausible" values. Sure, the exact interpretation is more nuanced than that of a credible interval, but at least there is a range of "plausible" values. This is particularly useful when the data set is large, leading to a tiny p-value yet a confidence interval that doesn't include zero but doesn't get far from it -- say $(0.000003, 0.000005)$. If you need to hit a value like $0.1$ for the work to be interesting, this allows you to qualify the statistical significance with added commentary about practical significance.

Good point that "statistically significant from 0" does not necessarily mean "significant" in a general sense

Yes, you should consider providing both the p-value for your chosen null and a confidence interval. The mathematical link between hypothesis testing and confidence intervals should not drive your analysis, they are different techniques with different aims.
The p-value is a measure of the consistency of the data with the chosen null hypothesis. The confidence interval gives an interval estimate of the difference in means with an attached confidence level. A confidence interval may be more useful for many readers than the formal test result (e.g., in drug effectiveness comparisons). Other readers may be particularly interested in your test result, while still other readers may prefer a different null hypothesis.
